# Suggestions on how to link multiple reservations to a single transaction

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create two tables in MySQL that can reference each other without creating duplicate entries.

This is a reservation system for a small little RV Park.

I have two tables ... one contains the reservations:

```
CREATE TABLE `reservations` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reserveid` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerid` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `findType` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rigType` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rigLength` int(2) DEFAULT 0,
  `siteNum` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `checkIn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `checkOut` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `adults` int(2) DEFAULT 0,
  `children` int(2) DEFAULT 0,
  `pets` int(2) DEFAULT 0,
  `enteredBy` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateCreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `paid` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `canceled` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `arrived` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `checkIn` (`checkIn`),
  KEY `checkOut` (`checkOut`),
  KEY `siteNum` (`siteNum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3431 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And the other contains the payments:

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `reserveid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `customerid` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_info` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_type` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processing_fee` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reserveid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Explanation**:
The `reserveid` is created using the PHP command uniquid() and each reservation gets assigned one.

Now if a person calls to make a reservation, and is only reserving one site, the system works perfectly.  One `reserveid` that links to the entry in the reservation table as well as the transaction table.  I need the transaction table in order to generate receipts for our customers.  This line item information is stored in the column named order_info as JSON.

**The problem**:

Say a customer calls and wants to book an RV site for Thanksgiving, and at the same time wants to come back for New Years'.  Two unique reservations, with a security deposit of $60 for the two dates, equals a single transaction of $120.  Credit Card companies can get jumpy when they see back to back transactions.

So the customer has now made two distinct reservations, each one being assigned its own `reserveid`, but we made only one charge to their card, how do I now associate two `reserveid`'s with a single transaction ID?  (I am using the Square PHP SDK exclusively).  The transaction_type will be "D" for deposit.

Do I now have to have an entry in the transaction table for each reservation, knowing that all of the information (other than the `reserveid` field) is exactly the same?  Seems like I would be flooding the table with a ton of duplicate information.  Also please keep in mind that when they arrive to check-in, there will be another transaction for the balance of their stay, but only for one reservation.

Comment: You should consider using logics similar to a shopping cart:

1. customer can choose multiple reservations.
2. when he/she checks out, all the reservations will be grouped together into a single payment, with appropriate deposit.
3. The payment reserveid will be stored in all the reserveraton records of this check-out, and so payment is linked to reservation in a one-to-many relationship.

In this way, there should be no unnecessary data redundancy. Let's further discuss if you have further questions.

Comment: @ken-lee Thank you.  So to clarify, add another column in the reservation table and store the order_id there, thus having that as the reference to the transaction.  But that leaves a mystery for how to handle any other transactions for that single reservation.  Like the balance due when they check in, or a guest arrives to spend the day and gets charged the visitor fee.  I guess that column could be comma delineated or json so that I can enter multiple order_id's?

Comment: To insert transactions like guest visits, u may insert a record into the reservation table (or rename it as service) and then recalculate the payment required. For the payments, if you anticipate that only two payments are sufficient, then store the deposit and balance payment in separate data fields are already ok. Otherwise u need an additional database table to store such data